# Best way to handle button's onPress from anywhere

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-context

### The idea

I have a screen, which has a 'global' button on top, and some inputs on the bottom.
By default this 'global' button will go to 'home' screen.

I want that button to work like this:

1. `[input focused] -> [button changes to 'back']` (when button is in 'back' state it will blur the input on press)
2. `[button clicked] -> [input blurred] -> [button changes back to 'home']`.

So I need to figure out how to handle button's `onPress` in any component in the app.

(With inputs I could do it with only `Keyboard.dismiss()`, but it's not only about inputs, I have some components that have their own way to do something on button's press)

---

### My approach

I've already made this working with context api, but right now I don't know was it a good idea or not...

I have a context provider that looks like this:

```
export default function MainButtonControlProvider({ children, goToHome }) {
  const [_type, setType] = useState('home');
  const [_onPressFn, setOnPressFn] = useState(() => goToHome);

  const reset = () => {
    setType('home');
    setOnPressFn(() => goToHome);
  }

  const set = ({ type, onPress }) => {
    setType(type);
    setOnPressFn(() => onPress);
  }

  return (
    <MainButtonControlContext.Provider value={{ _type, _onPressFn, reset, set }}>
      {children}
    </MainButtonControlContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

And that 'global' button like this:

```
export default function MainButton() {
  const { _type, _onPressFn } = useContext(MainButtonControlContext);

  const getIcon = () => {
    switch (_type) {
      case 'home':
        return <HomeIcon />
      case 'back':
        return <ChevronIcon size={32} rotation={-90} />
    }
  }

  return (
    <Button icon={getIcon()} onPress={_onPressFn} />
  )
}
```

And input like this:

```
export default function BasicInput() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const { set, reset } = useContext(MainButtonControlContext);

  return (
    <TextInput
      ref={inputRef}
      onFocus={() => set({ type: 'back', onPress: () => inputRef.current.blur() })
      onBlur={() => reset()}
    />
  )
}
```

---

### The problem

So the input is focused, it changes 'global' button's look and `onPress` function.

The problem is that after `set()` or `reset()` are executed, every other component in the tree that also uses these `set()` and `reset()` functions from the `MainButtonControlContext` - **rerender**...

It's pretty logical that they do this, because state is changed and functions are remade in the context provider... But how do I get around this?

I could've used `useCallback()` on the `set()` and `reset()` functions, but `set()` takes arguments and they are always different, so there's no point in that.

So I need a different approach

---

I have never used redux, but I think it is a good idea to learn it, so if someone has an approach with it, I wouldn't mind changing the whole app for PERFORMANCE

The thing that I didn't understand is how to handle button's `onPress` for that button, since redux state needs to be serializable...

---

**Edit:**

1. I tried to replace `set()` function in context provider with just `set` from `useState`, and wrap `reset()` with `useCallback`, and it worked! No more rerenders, but it's a pain to set all of the props when changing the button (I have 2 more states now). If someone knows how to change the `set` function from `useState` a bit without triggering rerenders, pls help ;)
2. I also tried to replace all of the `useState`s with `useReducer`, but for some reason change in `state` from `useReducer` won't trigger button's rerender...

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea to use context here

Comment: I kinda like the redux idea. You can have a state in redux that is `homeType` and then you can create a component that is bound to redux, like `<DynamicHomeButton />` which will automatically re-render only itself when the redux state changes. This would improve performance  because only the button will re-render.

Comment: @noodlejs I actually do the same with contexts here, I just don't know how to handle the button press by different components in the app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach with Context API didn't work. I fixed rerenders of the components that used context by wrapping `set` and `reset` function in `useCallback`(I didn't know that I can pass arguments to `useCallback` ), but it did nothing because ALL of the components inside provider still rerendered after state change... I tried even memoizing the state, still didn't work.

I think I am missing something with using context api. If someone knows how to deal with state inside Providers, let me know, will be a good lesson ;)

---

**I ended up using [zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand) to store the state needed for the main button.** Redux felt like overkill for such a simple app and also I don't have any experience with it.

So I just created a store for the main button, like this:

```js
import create from 'zustand';

export const useMainButtonStore = create((set, get) => ({
  type: 'home',
  onPress: () => console.warn('No onPress set in MainButttonStore.'),
  _default: null,

  set: (payload) => set(state => ({
    /* state from payload */
  })),
  reset: () => set(state => ({
    /* check if _default is set and then set state to _default */
  })),
  setDefault: (payload) => set(state => ({
    /* set _default on initial app render */
  })),
}))
```

And then in components.
These 2 can actually be combined in one line using [shallow](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand#selecting-multiple-state-slices).

```js
  const setMainButton = useMainButtonStore(state => state.set);
  const resetMainButton = useMainButtonStore(state => state.reset);
```

One concern that I had is whether it is ok to store functions. Up to this point I had no problems with this.
I'm sure there will be problems when persisting this store, because functions are not serializable, but there's no point in that :)